# Run jar compiled on 32 bit client on 64 bit server

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, dll

Right, i have looked all over the net and tried most solutions suggested but still nothing seems to work.

I'm trying to run a .jar file which was compiled on a 32 bit windows client using JRE7 and JDK1.7 in eclipse, on a 64 bit server again using JRE7 and JDK1.7. This works on one server but not another, seems strange that it works on one but not another when the both (seem) to be set up the same... any ideas what could be different on the other server that could be causing the error below?

from what i have read it seems that its trying to access the wrong dll? how would i get to access the correct one?

we are setting the oracle and java home paths to point to 32 bit versions etc.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN\ocijdbc10.dll: can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform......
```

any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Your library seems to be not pure Java. It contains/uses native code.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you run a 32 bit JVM ? You should only get the error if you run a 64 bit JVM

Comment: Setting JAVA_HOME has no effect on the VM under windows if you don't start it with "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"

Comment: We use "SET JAVA7_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin" in the batch and also the oracle cp file when we run it

Comment: Yes i'm pointing it to the 32 bit JVM

Comment: do not wrap any jdbc drivers into jar. Especially not the OCI ones. Is there any reason why you do not use thin JDBC Oracle drivers?

Comment: @Aaron Do you also use JAVA7_HOME for starting the vm, or do you just set it?

Comment: @Aaron setting JAVA7_HOME have no effect, unless **you**  use JAVA7_HOME somewhere when launching the JVM.

Comment: @ivan we are using oracle wallet to connect to the database and the oci driver was what we have working. when you say don't wrap them in the jar what do you mean? how else can i do it?

Comment: @nos we set JAVA7_HOME to the path in my previous comment and then we use the following to run the jar file: "%JAVA7_HOME%\java" -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2 etc

Comment: I think that wallets are supported by thin drivers too. Why don't you put jdbc drivers into class path?

Comment: On the problem server the following happens - If I compile and execute with 32-bit Java / 32-bit Oracle 10 it throws InvocationTargetException caused by "UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path".  If I compile and execute with 64-bit Java / 64-bit Oracle 11 it runs ok. If I compile and execute with 32-bit Java / 32-bit Oracle 11 it throws InvocationTargetException caused by the error "UnsatisfiedLinkError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getLibraryVersionNumber()I". I'm just confused now on what the problem is :S